# How many proper divisor (that is, divisiors other than 1or 7200) does 7200 have?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring, divisor-counting-function

How many proper divisor (that is, divisiors other than 1or 7200) does 7200 have ?

Comment: Have a look at this [Determine-the-Number-of-Divisors-of-an-Integer](https://www.wikihow.com/Determine-the-Number-of-Divisors-of-an-Integer)

Comment: **Hint:** $7200 = 2^5\times 3^2\times 5^2$